# Records visibility in Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, sharing

I have created a community in salesforce , i have a customer community user  , to be login into salesforce community as user , all i do is go to contact record and manage ,and login as customer as user , in community i have given permission for case object , when i click on go button i need to get the contact's account cases ,but am getting all cases , i have controlled OWD settings for cases to private , when i do so am only able to see the current logged user records only not all contacts account cases ,

How can i achieve this ..

Comment: Are Accounts public read/write, and is there a case sharing rule?

Comment: Yes @DavidSchach ACCOUNTS are read/write .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant access to Customer Communities users to a limited subset of standard objects and all custom objects using Sharing Sets and Sharing Groups. Customer Communities users do not have access to the full sharing model but you can grant access using sharing sets and groups based on a contact or account lookup from Case.

More information can be found here:
[Granting High-Volume Community Users Access to Records](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_setting_light_users.htm&language=en_US)